# How to scroll two UITableView toghether vertically

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have two `UITableView`. I need to scrolling toghether vertically.

I tried to insert both tables inside a `UIScrollView` and disabling scrolling of `UITableView`.
It works but the `UITableView` which is below is cut it seems as if the table size was set to the maximum size of the screen).
The `UITableView` i put them inside the view through the storyboard.
I tried to increase the frame of the table within the `viewDidLoad` method but does not work. If I insert it inside the method `viewDidAppear` works but it makes me a failure when I click on a UICell and then came back.

Any suggest?

Comment: Why you not using one tableView but with couple of sections.

Comment: becaouse one table view is grouped style the other is plain

Answer (score 4):

you should work with sections. But if this is not an option for what ever reason you could listen to the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method and set the offset of the two tables as appropriate. Small Example:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   if (scrollView == self.firstTable) {
      self.secondTable.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
   } else {
      self.firstTable.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
   }
}
```

you might need to store the touched table in an ivar to determine which scrollevents are initialized by user-interaction and which by your code to avoid 'scroll'-loops.

**EDIT:**

I might misunderstood your question. You want them to behave as one Table?

Comment: Thanks. I try it but the same situation (tha secondTableView it cut)

Comment: Yes Jonathan, I want to behave as one Table